# Proving discontinuity at $\,x =1\,$ using $\,\varepsilon$-$\delta\,$ definition

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, epsilon-delta, piecewise-continuity

I was doing a proof for discontinuity using $\,\varepsilon$-$\delta\,$ definition but I’m not sure whether the proof is right. Would you mind checking it for me please, thanks!

$g(x)=\begin{cases}\dfrac{1}{1-x}\;,\quad& x\neq1\\0\;,&x=1\end{cases}$

For the proof, I have chosen $\,\varepsilon = 1$.

And said for $x\in [0,2]\cap(1-\delta, 1+\delta)\,$ where $\,x\neq1$

$|x-1|<\delta\,$ but $\,|g(x)-g(1)|\geqslant1\,,$

Is this right?

Thanks!

Comment: You are looking at a function $g(x)$. What is $f(x)$? Which case in the definition of $g(x)$ has an obvious typo?

Comment: Yes, apart from this typo it seems correct, but better *choose* (for *any* $\delta>0$) some $x$ (in fact any of those you mention will do: e.g. $x=\min(2,1+\delta/2)$).

Comment: Is not correct. You need to prove that no matter which $\delta>0$, there is always an $\epsilon$ that contradicts the definition thus rendering the function discontinuous.

Answer (score 1):

The function g(x) is continuous at $x=x_0$ if
$$\forall \epsilon >0, \exists \delta >0:|x-x_0|<\delta\Rightarrow |g(x)-g(x_0)|<\epsilon$$

The function g(x) is discontinuous at $x=x_0$ if

$$\exists \epsilon >0\,,\forall \delta >0\,,\exists x\in(x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta) :|g(x)-g(x_0)|\ge \epsilon\,.$$

In this case $x_0=1; g(x_0)=0\,.$

Lets take $\epsilon=1$. Observe that, for $0<|x-1|<1$,

$$
\frac{1}{|x-1|}>\epsilon,\quad\text{ or equivalently, }\quad
\left|\frac{1}{x-1}-0\right| \gt \epsilon\,.
$$
That is:
$$
|g(x)-g(1)| \gt \epsilon\,.
$$
This shows that for $\delta=1$ every $x\in(1-\delta,1)\cup(1,1+\delta)=(0,1)\cup(1,2)$ satisfies
$$\tag{1}
|g(x)-g(1)|>\epsilon.
$$
Clearly, for any other $\delta>0$ we can find at least one
$x\in(1-\delta,1)\cup(1,1+\delta)$ that satisfies (1) as well because the
intersection of this set with the previous one, $(0,1)\cup(1,2)\,,$ is not empty.

This finishes the proof that $g(x)$ is discontinuous at $x=1\,.$

Comment: I cannot follow that definition of discontinuity. For $x=x_0$ the condition $|x-x_0|<\delta$ is true but $|g(x)-g(x_0)|\ge\epsilon$ is false, no matter if $g$ is continuous or discontinuous.

Comment: The truth is in implication not in parts of it. Take a step function of the form $f(x)=\left \{ \begin{align} 1&,x\le3\\4&,x>3\end{align}\right.$. The value $f(x)=3$ can not be found on any vicinity of 3. There is $\epsilon=3$ for which $\forall x \in (3-\delta, 3+\delta)\Rightarrow |f(x)-f(3)|\ge\epsilon$

Comment: As far as I can tell: For this $f$, $f(3)=1$ and $\forall x\in(3-\delta,3)$ we have $|f(x)-f(3)|=0\,.$ This is in stark contrast to your last claim.

Comment: I changed it to f(3)=3. Then it has to be the centered interval, not half of it.

Comment: The centered interval contains $x=3$ and for this $x$ the inequality $|f(x)-f(3)|\ge\epsilon$ only holds for $\epsilon=0\,.$ That was my point about your definition of the discontinuity of $g$.

Comment: If you apply the rules of negation to your correct definition of the continuity of $g$ the discontinuity becomes
$$
\exists \epsilon>0\,\forall \delta>0\,,\color{red}{\exists x\in(x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)}: |g(x)-g(x_0)|\ge \epsilon\,.
$$

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that. Please be so kind to write the answer for everyone to benefit.

Comment: I think it is better if you or I edit your answer. There is not much to change. You want to give it a go?

Comment: Of course but you deserve the credit, not me. I’m good with what I’ve learned today.

Comment: As you can see, I needed three attempts to get it right. :) Please review.